# padEnd() adds 0 in wrong place

Tags: javascript, html, dom

so I'm making this calculator app and I'm close to finishing it, but there's something wrong with the code I wrote specifically when using the padEnd() method, so the idea here is that when I type a number that has a fraction like 3.20 I need it to show as 3.20 not 3.2. I managed to do that with padEnd() like so:

```
 function getTotal() {
    d += Math.floor(re1);
    p += getValue(re1);

    if (p >= 24) {
        p -= 24;
        ++d;
    }
    if (p < 10) {
        total = d + p / 10;
    } else {
        total = d + p / 100;
    }
    if (p % 10 === 0) {
        ptag.textContent = total.toString().padEnd(total.length + 1) + "0";
    } else
    {
        ptag.textContent = total;
    }
 }

function enter() {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == "13") {
            getTotal()
            input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - input.value.length);
            ptag.style.marginLeft = "11%";
            ptag.style.color = "#fff";
        }
    })
}

enter();

function plusBtn() {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
        if (/[+]/g.test(e.key)) {
            addNclear()
        }
    })
}

plusBtn();

function addNclear() {
getTotal();
input.value = input.value.substring(0, input.value.length - input.value.length);
}

function getValue(v) {
return +v.toString().match(/\.(\d*)/)[1] || 0;
}
```

for better demonstration of the issue visit this [codepen](https://codepen.io/person_0/pen/wvawBaY) I made and type 3.20 + 2.4 it should = 6, but instead it outputs 60 because of the padEnd I added.

Now the whole purpose of this question is how can I make padEnd() add the zero only when I type a fraction?

I'll add an image with the problem if you don't wanna visit the [codepen](https://codepen.io/person_0/pen/wvawBaY)

[image: image with the problem]

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: And won't using `toFixed` fit your needs?

Comment: @mbojko can you please demonstrate how it's used in an answer. I'm still a beginner and I don't know how to exactly use it even after I looked it up

Comment: Replacing this `total.toString().padEnd(total.length + 1) + "0"` with `total.toFixed(2)` (`toFixed(2)` creates a string with exactly 2 digits after the `.`).